# Jquery - Break up values into individual input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following app copy's excel values and breaks them up into individual input fields.

Everything works great but i'm loosing the first value.

For example, if i create 5 entries. The first input field's id is 001, second is 002 etc etc.

When i copy and paste an excel column, the value for 002 gets copied to the 001 id.

Here's the data I'm copying from Excel

1
2
3
4
5

!http://imgur.com/nxe6yDq

https://jsfiddle.net/jdarville/r9tp7762/1/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#uncinfo").bind("paste", function(e){
        // access the clipboard using the api
        var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
        arr = pastedData.split(/\s+/);
        for(i=1; i < arr.length; i++){
            $("#unc"+i).val(arr[i]);
        }
    } );
});
```

Comment: thats cause `i` starts at 1, in your for loop

Comment: .. but the first element in a JS array has index 0

Comment: Try pasting into a Notepad and see what shows up, maybe the data is not organized how you think it is.

Comment: Also, do a `console.log( pastedData )` and look at what is grabbed from the clipboard, then adjust appropriately.

Comment: if i add an input value with the id of 000, then it works...

Comment: change $("#unc"+i).val(arr[i]) to $("#unc"+i).val(arr[i -1]) as array starts with zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#uncinfo").bind("paste", function(e){
    // access the clipboard using the api
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    arr = pastedData.split(/\s+/);
    for(i=1; i <= arr.length; i++){
     $("#unc"+i).val(arr[i -1]);
    }
   });
```

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/y6tkyLjy/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `i` to 0

```
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        $("#unc"+i).val(arr[i]);
    }
```

Comment: i tried that and got the same result --> https://jsfiddle.net/jdarville/r9tp7762/1/

Comment: In your question, please paste the output of what the `clipboardData` contains when you copy from excel

Answer (score 0):

this happens because your arrays are 0 based, while your inputs are 1 based,
for example for usernames you should use:

```
for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    $("#user"+(i+1)).val(arr[i]);
}
```

test this approach here:

https://jsfiddle.net/1jpL4L2n/1/

another solution would be to move the id incrementing after creating the table rows:

```
$("#table").append('<tr>...</tr>');
x++; //text box increment
```

this way you will have your input ids 0 based: #unc0, unc1, ...
in this case your loop for filling would be:

```
for(i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
    $("#user"+i).val(arr[i]);
}
```

you can test this approach here:

https://jsfiddle.net/h50h35vj/2/